# How to Update a Datagrid after adding a new Record Instantly - I have to reload the page in order to see the new contents in the data grid

Tags: c#

On my add new Order form I wish to see the data grid update instantly after the submit button is pressed, However the page must be exited and re-entered again in order to see the Updated Datagrid contents. The contents of the table is held in a Obserable collection. And the data grid is contained on a page that is placed in a Frame.

Code For adding the Contents to the Table shown below. I am a amateur so please don't slam my (probably) bad code.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // submut button
{
    int customerid = CustomerList[customerCB.SelectedIndex].Item1;
    int Starter = StarterList[starterCB.SelectedIndex].Item1;
    int Main = MainList[mainCB.SelectedIndex].Item1;
    int Dessert = DessertList[dessertCB.SelectedIndex].Item1;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.DBconnection))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Order] (CustID, [Order Date], [Function Date], Venue, [No of People], Starter, Main, Dessert)"
            + " VALUES (@CID, @oDate, @FDate, @venue, @people, @course1, @course2, @course3)", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", customerid);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oDate", orderdate.SelectedDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FDate", functiondate.SelectedDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue", venue.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@people", number.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course1", Starter);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course2", Main);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course3", Dessert);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a problem with the Data Entered : Error Code : ", ex.Message);
        }

        this.Close();
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you update/set your data grid.  Assuming your data grid should reflect database values, after updating your database, you need to make a SELECT from the appropriate tables, put that in an ObservableCollection and reset the datasource for your grid.  Also, calling Close() is not needed for your sql connection when it is inside of a using statement (it is called by the .NET framework when the code exits the using statement (its the point of the using statement))

Comment: Just a row to the datagrid containing the same data that u insert in the db

Comment: Removing extra indent and spaces so code is condensed and more readable